# How to use a MySQL view and ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Question #1 - How to make a view of a table1 where if a certain field in the table is present in table2, then exclude that record from the view?

Question #2 - How to order the results in DESC order by the id in Table1.

```
SELECT table1.source_id
FROM table1
WHERE table1.source_id NOT IN (SELECT table2.source_id from table2)
ORDER BY table1.source_id DESC;
```

Comment: ORDER BY does not change which rows are selected. It changes only the order in which they are returned.

Comment: `fee_id` or `fee_source_id` ??

Comment: What you are looking for is a JOIN clause, check out some Stack Overflow questions related to joins.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join

Comment: Except I'm looking not to JOIN but do something where an id is NOT IN (Select ...) Y/N? Thanks

Comment: It's not nice to change your question so radically that the answers no longer make sense. :(

Comment: Ben I think you don't understand what a JOIN is -- don't think of it so literally.  JOIN just means you want to base your query on the content of multiple tables.  You don't have to select content from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use an "anti-join" pattern. That's a LEFT JOIN with a predicate that excludes any rows that are matched,

```
SELECT t1.source_id
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.source_id = t1.source_id 
 WHERE t2.source_id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY t1.source_id DESC
```

(Performance of this statement will be best if there are indexes on both table1 an table2 with a leading column of source_id.)

Another alternative is to use a NOT EXISTS predicate

```
SELECT t1.source_id
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM table2 t2
          WHERE t2.source_id = t1.source_id
       )
 ORDER
    BY t1.source_id DESC
```

(The MySQL optimizer may run that as an "anti-join" as well, rather than as a dependent subquery; you'd need to check the output from EXPLAIN to verify.)

On large sets, either of those is going to perform much BETTER than a query that includes a derived table, such as one with a `NOT IN (subquery)` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, what are you talking about, but from your question I conclude this.
Let say `A` and `B` are two tables and their common fields are `fee_id`.
Then try this.

`select a.name,b.fee_id from A a,B a where a.fee_id=b.fee_id`

Above query will return all the data from both table by checking `fee_id` in both tables.

Now, as you said, you need `ORDER BY`. Then, do something like.

`select a.name,b.fee_id from A a,B a where a.fee_id=b.fee_id ORDER BY a.name DESC`

If you want to show your information in `DESC` order of name.

**UPDATE**

**How to create view**

`create view viewname as (select * from table1)`

**Solution for your 1st question**

Let say `name` field is common between both table and you want those record in that view which are **UNIQUE** in both table. I mean, if `table1` has one record, but same record is not present in `table2`

`create view viewname as (select * from table2 UNION (select * from table1 where name not in(select name from table2)))`

**Example :**

```
NAME |                    NAME |
-------------            ----------------
ABC  |                   ABC   |
CDF  |                   GHI   |

It will return 

NAME |                    
-------------            
ABC  |                   
CDF  |     
GHI  |
```

**Solution for 2nd question**

You have provided this query in your question. And, i don't feel anything wrong in that.

```
SELECT source_id
FROM table1
WHERE source_id NOT IN (SELECT source_id from table2)
ORDER BY source_id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you need to change the 'a' after the upper case B to a lower case 'b' ? Also, I am looking to do the opposite of the where a.fee_id = b.fee_id... I want to way "where not in"? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've changed my question around a bit to make it more clear :) thanks

Comment: Question #1 - How to make a view of a table1 where if a certain field in the table is present in table2, then exclude that record from the view?

Question #2 - How to order the results in DESC order by the id in Table1.

SELECT table1.source_id
FROM table1
WHERE table1.source_id NOT IN (SELECT table2.source_id from table2)
ORDER BY table1.source_id DESC;

Comment: I think I follow your answr except two things:
1) I think you meant to make the part like this "A a,B a" have a lower case 'b'?
2) I am trying to select where the fee_id's are not equal (not where they are equal). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get those `fee_source` that is not found neither in the `a_aif` table nor `a_proxy` table, with `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL`, then you can put an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT a_aif.fee_source_id source_id
    FROM a_aif 
    left JOIN a_fees ON a_fees.fee_source = a_aif.fee_source_id 
    WHERE a_fees.fee_source IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a_proxy.fee_source_id
    FROM a_proxy
    left JOIN a_fees ON a_fees.fee_source = a_proxy.fee_source_id
    WHERE a_fees.fee_source IS NULL
) t
ORDER BY source_id DESC;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a79b/6)

Answer (score 0):

I used `OFFSET 0 ROWS` to force `order by` clause

```
select count(*) from (
select column_name 
from table_A
order by column_name OFFSET 0 ROWS) abc
```